# Parameterize table name for cursor bound variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, database-cursor

Below is the function where the records are stored in a record variable for each iteration. Here the table name is hardcoded for cursor bound variable. Is there is any way I can pass the table name as a parameter through this function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1()
  RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
   curs2 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM datas.test1000;
begin

FOR recordvar IN curs2 LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE 'recordvar: %',recordvar; 
END LOOP ;

end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, not for a bound cursor.

But you can easily pass a name for opening an [**unbound cursor**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-DECLARATIONS). There is an [example in the manual doing precisely that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN58722).

Your function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test2(_tbl regclass)
  RETURNS void AS 
$func$
DECLARE
   _curs refcursor;
   rec   record;
BEGIN

OPEN _curs FOR EXECUTE
 'SELECT * FROM ' || _tbl;

LOOP
   FETCH NEXT FROM _curs INTO rec;
   EXIT WHEN rec IS NULL;

   RAISE NOTICE 'rec: %', rec; 
END LOOP;

END
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

The [special `FOR` loop](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP) can only be used with *bound* cursors. I supplied an alternative.
More explanation in this closely related answer:
[Update record of a cursor where the table name is a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830398/update-record-of-a-cursor-where-the-table-name-is-a-parameter/18833367#18833367)

I use the [object identifier type `regclass`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html) to pass the table name to avoid SQL injection.
More about that in [this related answer on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718):