# looping through cursor results

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, cursor, plpgsql

I am trying to loop through a cursor(plpgsql) result,but somehow nothing is being printed on output console.

```
create or replace function curs() returns refcursor as 
$body$
declare
    curs cursor for select id from stores;
    store stores.id%TYPE;
begin
    open curs;
    fetch curs into store;
    loop
    exit when not found;
        raise notice 'Value: %',store;
    end loop;
    close curs;
end
$body$ language plpgsql;

select curs();
```

How do I implement a proper loop?

Database Version : 9.0
Table **stores** with columns id,name

Comment: This question should also provide the table definition and your Postgres version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter updated the question

Comment: But that's not a table definition. A table definition is a complete `CREATE TABLE` script showing data types and constraints, or what you get with `\d tbl` in psql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your function does not *return* anything, you just produce notices. In pgAdmin, those would be output in the "Messages" pane, not in the "Data Output" pane.

I assume you want to actually return values ...
But typically, you don't need an explicit cursor to loop. Use the more convenient ***implicit*** cursor of a `FOR` loop:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_loop()
  RETURNS SETOF int AS 
$func$
DECLARE
   _id int;  -- assuming data type integer
BEGIN
   FOR _id IN
      SELECT id FROM stores ORDER BY id
   LOOP
      RETURN NEXT _id;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Note the call syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM test_loop();
```

Typically, you don't even need a loop. Just plain SQL ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_loop1()
  RETURNS SETOF int AS 
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT id FROM stores ORDER BY id;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Which can be simplified to an SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_loop2()
  RETURNS SETOF int AS 
$func$
   SELECT id FROM stores ORDER BY id;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Related answers with more details and explanation:

- [Update record of a cursor where the table name is a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830398/update-record-of-a-cursor-where-the-table-name-is-a-parameter/18833367#18833367)
- [Loop on tables with PL/pgSQL in Postgres 9.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266345/loop-on-tables-with-pl-pgsql-in-postgres-9-0/15278973#15278973)

Comment: Yes.The first example works.
But what if I don't want to use a loop?
how can I then read the values individually and return them?