# How to pass a table name for a cursor as function parameter?

Tags: postgresql, cursor, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1, dynamic-sql

In PostgreSQL 9.1, I need to pass a table name as parameter to my function to be used in a cursor - and then call the function like:

```
select myfunction('tableA');
```

or:

```
select myfunction('tableB')
```

I have tried this:

```
 create or replace function myfunction(sid text) 
 returns integer as $BODY$
 declare
      bids cursor is select id from sid; --line 4
 begin
      for bid in bids loop
          --some logic
      end loop;
      return 1;
 end;
 $BODY$
 language plpgsql volatile;
```

I am getting `error on line 4`. And I understood it, it's not allowed to pass a table name as function parameter where it's allowed rest (selection, projection).

Are there alternatives to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only values can be parameterized in SQL commands, not identifiers or key words. And it currently works only for `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` commands. Details:

- [Error when setting n_distinct using a plpgsql variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025308/error-when-setting-n-distinct-using-a-plpgsql-variable/36025963#36025963)

You need dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE` in plpgsql.
Combine that with the implicit cursor of a `FOR` loop, which is typically simpler and faster than an explicit cursor. [Instructions in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING)

I also suggest to use a `regclass` parameter to pass *valid table names* safely.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(_tbl regclass) 
  RETURNS int  AS
$func$
DECLARE
   bid integer;  -- appropriate data type!
BEGIN
   FOR bid IN EXECUTE
      'SELECT id FROM ' || _tbl
   LOOP
      -- statements can use bid
      RAISE NOTICE '%', bid;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN 1;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT myfunction('tableA');  -- careful: case sensitive!
```

More explanation:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

And typically, there is a faster set-based solution that does not need to loop at all.

---

If you positively *need* a cursor, declare an ***unbound cursor*** and open it with [**`OPEN FOR EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN63248):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction(_tbl text)  -- could be regclass again
  RETURNS int AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _bids refcursor;
   _rec  record;
BEGIN
   OPEN _bids FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT id FROM ' || quote_ident(_tbl);  -- text must be escaped

   LOOP
      FETCH NEXT FROM _bids INTO _rec;
      EXIT WHEN _rec IS NULL;

      -- some logic
      RAISE NOTICE '%', _rec.id;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN 1;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Same call. More details in this closely related answer:

- [Update record of a cursor where the table name is a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830398/update-record-of-a-cursor-where-the-table-name-is-a-parameter/18833367#18833367)

Comment: I tried this. actually I want to use the input for cursor (in declare block).

Comment: @Spike: I added another answer how to use a cursor for this.

Comment: Working fine. Thanks.